# multivariate limits proof

Tags: limits

Could anyone help me with this proof?

Given a map $f : \mathbb R^m \to\mathbb R^n,$ prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L$ holds if and only if

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a}  \|f(x) − L\| = 0$$

does, for $x \in\mathbb R^n$ where $f(x)$ is a vector function while $||f(x)||$ is the vector norm.

For my proof,

For  $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta$
such that 
$$||f(x)-L||< \epsilon$$
whenever $$0<||x-a||<  \delta.$$

Let $||f(x)-a||<\epsilon \Rightarrow |f(x)-L| <||f(x)-L|| < \epsilon = \delta.$

Is my proof correct? And and do I have to prove two ways because of the if and only if? If so how how do I prove two ways? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You know that

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ iff for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that

$0<||x-a||<\delta\implies ||f(x)-L||<\epsilon$, and

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}||f(x)-L||=0$ iff for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that

$0<||x-a||<\delta\implies \left\vert||f(x)-L||-0\right\vert<\epsilon$.

To show that these conditions are equivalent, you just need to show that $||f(x)-L||=\left\vert||f(x)-L||-0\right\vert$.